# i am creating a chat bot which will create an email template by capturing some Details in the Slots section and then fill it in the text paraghraph

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

i am creating a chat bot which will create an email template by capturing some Details in the Slots section and then fill it in the text paragraph

I have the below Entities created based on pattern
Customer name
Account name
Address
Issue

one intent Called templates
templates

when try to get the variable in the response it not showings the text input by user

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb2TA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y04vg.png)

what i am doing wrong or how i achieve the format at the end to have this text filled in with variable

Hello $customer_name we received case for $Account_name at $address with the Below $issue